# why did I have to run this git command?

Tags: linux, git

After checking out the branch of a colleague, at some point
I couldn't `push` or `pull` from `remote`.
Each time I ran `git push` or `git push origin branch_name` or those variant, I always got a `everything up to date` even though I had committed changes. Ultimately, what did the trick was `git push -f origin HEAD:origin/branch_name`. So my question is, why did I have to run this? what did I do to get there?

the fatal error I got was:
`fatal: You are not currently on a branch.To push history leading to current (detached HEAD) state now, use: git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>`

Comment: Just as a quick question, how do you normally commit code? Is it through an IDE or from the terminal?

Comment: I only use a terminal for committing code.

Comment: We'd need to see the output of `git status`, and perhaps also `git fetch origin`, `git branch -r`, and `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch`.

Comment: I agree with @torek `git status` would be useful to understand where you were. Were you also tracking the right remote branch? `git branch -vv` to check.

Comment: I'll not be allowed to show all those information because it's at my workplace. I'll try to provide as much information but if it's not enough I'll understand. I had one file committed with changes. `git status` didn't return nothing after I committed. All my attempts to `push` were unsuccessful. `git fetch -a` didn't return nothing as well. the last step I had were to `git checkout origin/branch_name`.

Comment: When I tried to `push` from there I got the following message: `fatal: You are not currently on a branch.To push history leading to current (detached HEAD) state now, use: git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>`. Which I did and it worked

Comment: That error message is important. Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably edit (parts of) your last two ... er, now, *three*—comments into your question, but for now, I'll just quote them here:

> I found where I might have off road. When I checked-out the branch I was going to work on, I got this message (let's called the branch `b1`:
>
> ```
> Branch b1 set up to track remote branch b1 from origin.
> Switched to a new branch 'b1'.
> ```
>
> I checked-out the branch this way:
>
> ```
> git checkout b1.
> ```
>
> Then when I tried to push I did:
>
> ```
> git push --set-upstream origin b1.
> Branch b1 set up to track remote branch b1 from origin.
> Everything up to date
> ```

OK, in that case you are probably fine.

## `git checkout`

The problem you are running into here (well, in my opinion it's a problem) is that `git checkout` crams three or four (or more, depending on how you count) *different* things into one command.

Normally you would use:

```
git checkout somebranch
```

to check out (switch to) your local branch `somebranch`.  Of course, that's great for branches you *already have*, but no good for branches you *don't* have locally yet.  So Git crams another, different, command into `git checkout`: the "create new branch, then switch to it" command.

*Normally* this command is spelled `git checkout -b newbranch`.  The `-b` flag means "create new".  It's pretty reasonable to have this command spelled the same as `git checkout`, with just a flag, since we're switching to this newly created branch, but it probably would be clearer if it were a separate command, such as `git create-and-then-switch-to-new-branch`.

Now, pretty often, when you are creating a new *local* branch, you are doing so with the *intent* of having it "track" (as its "upstream") some existing *remote-tracking* branch, `origin/b1` or whatever.  In this case, you originally had to type in:

```
git checkout -b b1 --track origin/b1
```

which is still really obvious: create new branch `b1`, base it off remote-tracking branch `origin/b1`, and make it *track* (have as its upstream) `origin/b1`.  Again, this might be clearer as `git create-and-then-switch-to`, but it's not so bad to have it shoved into `git checkout`, plus `checkout` is a lot shorter to type!

Now, many years ago (back in 2013 or so), the Git folks saw that this action was pretty common, and decided to make Git do it "magically" for you ***under certain conditions***.  If you write:

```
git checkout b1
```

**and** you don't currently have a branch `b1` **and** you *do* currently have an `origin/b1` **and** you don't have any *other* remote-tracking branch whose name ends in `b1`, ***then*** (and only then!), `git checkout` uses the create-and-then-switch-to-new-branch command, *with* the `--track` flag.  So:

```
git checkout b1
```

means

```
git checkout -b b1 --track origin/b1
```

*in this one special (but common) case*.

#### `--track` means "set upstream"

Each branch (well, each *named*, local, branch) can have one (1) "upstream" set.  The upstream of a branch has a bunch of uses: `git status`, `git fetch`, `git merge`, `git rebase`, and `git push` all look at the upstream.  Having an upstream set makes `git status` show how many commits you are ahead and/or behind of the current branch's upstream.  And, it lets you run all the other commands with no additional arguments: they can figure out where to fetch from, or what to merge or rebase, or what to push, using the current branch's name and its upstream setting.

Branches do not *have* to have an upstream, and a new branch you create doesn't, by default.  Moreover, if it's a "very new" branch—one that does not exist on `origin`, for instance—there's no `origin/name` yet to have as an upstream in the first place.  But when you create a new branch *from* a remote-tracking branch, setting the remote-tracking branch as the upstream of the new branch is almost always the right thing.

(Note: having an upstream also affects `git pull` because `git pull` is just `git fetch` followed by either `git merge` or `git rebase`.  Until they are very familiar with Git, I think most people are noticeably better off running `git fetch` first, then `git rebase` or `git merge` second, depending on which one they want—and more often, that's actually `git rebase`, which is *not* the default for `git pull`: `git pull` defaults to using `git merge` second.  Once they are familiar with the fetch-and-whatever sequence, *then* people can configure `git pull` to do the one they intend, and use `git pull` as a shortcut to run both commands.  However, there are times to keep them separate anyway.)

#### For completeness

The other things that `git checkout` can do, that *don't* change the current branch, are:

- copy files from the index to the work-tree: `git checkout -- <paths>`, including the special `git checkout --ours` and `git checkout --theirs` variations
- copy files from specified commits to the index and then on to the work-tree: `git checkout <tree-ish> -- <paths>`
- restore conflicted merge files to their conflicted state: `git checkout -m -- <paths>` (as with `--ours` and `--theirs`, this only works during a conflicted merge)
- interactively patch files: `git checkout -p` (this variant gets especially complicated and I'm not going to address it further)

The `checkout` command can also "detach HEAD" (see previous answer below) and create "orphan" branches, but both of these effectively change your current branch, so they don't fall into this special "non-branch-changing" class of `checkout` operations.

#### So what happened with the first `git push`

When you ran:

```
git push --set-upstream origin b1
```

you told your Git to contact the other Git on `origin`, give it the commit ID to which your branch `b1` pointed, see if it needed any of those commits and files (it didn't), and then ask it to set *its* branch name `b1` to point to the same commit.

Now, you'd just created your own local `b1` from your `origin/b1`, which you recently `git fetch`-ed from `origin`, so *your* `b1` already pointed to the *same* commit (you did not make any new commits) and hence your `git push` gave them their own commit hash back and they said "Well, gosh, that's what I already have!  We're all up-to-date!"  And then their Git and your Git said goodbye to each other, and your Git carried out your last instruction: `--set-upstream`.

This changed the upstream of your local branch `b1` to `origin/b1`.  Of course, this was *already* the upstream for your local branch `b1`, so that was not a big change. :-)  But your Git did it anyway, and then reported that everything was still up to date.

#### Earlier answer (was mostly done when you added your third comment)

> ... I had one file committed with changes. `git status` didn't return nothing after I committed.

`git status` should always print *something*, such as (two actual examples):

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

or:

```
HEAD detached at 08bb350
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

In this second case, you are in "detached HEAD" mode.  This special mode means you are not on a branch—or it may be more accurate to say that you are on the (single, special-case) *anonymous* branch that goes away as soon as you get on any *other* branch.

Any commits you make while in detached HEAD mode are perfectly fine, normal commits—except that there ***is no branch name that will make them permanent.***  This means these commits can go away once you switch to some other branch.

> All my attempts to `push` were unsuccessful.

Again, actual `git push` output might help here, so one could tell *why* the push failed or did nothing.  If it complained about being in "detached HEAD" mode, that would be significant: we would know that you were in the detached HEAD mode.

> `git fetch -a` didn't return nothing as well.

(Just an aside: It's a bit odd to use `-a` here: that flag is almost never useful to humans and is intended more for scripting purposes.  It just makes your `fetch` append to `FETCH_HEAD` rather than overwriting it.  The special `FETCH_HEAD` name is meant for scripts to use.)

> the last step I had were to `git checkout origin/branch_name`.

This will take you off whatever branch you were on before, and put you in "detached HEAD" mode.  If you used to be in "detached HEAD" mode, it will abandon your previous anonymous branch and put you on a new, different anonymous branch.

Any commits you made while on the previous anonymous branch are ... well, not *lost*, precisely, but are now difficult to find (and set to expire after 30 days).

> When I tried to push from there I got the following message:
>
> ```
> fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
> To push history leading to current (detached HEAD) state now, use: 
>
>     git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>.
> ```
>
> Which I did [`... HEAD:origin/branch_name`] and it worked

Yes, but alas, this did nothing useful, because you are now on an anonymous branch that is *exactly the same as* `origin/branch_name`.  This ends up asking the remote to create—on the remote, as a *local* branch there—the name `origin/branch_name`.  That's probably not a good idea, since having a local branch named `origin/branch_name` is like having a bicycle named "motorcycle".  If you also have a motorcycle and ask your friend to bring you "motorcycle", which will he bring you, the bicycle named "motorcycle", or the motorcycle?

Answer (score 3):

**Current State:** Your head isn't attached to a branch, so you pushed with the branch whose history was the same as the remotes. You were working with a detached head, so when you pushed the head instead of the branch, it worked.

If you do a `git status` it with show:

> HEAD detached at XXXXXXX

**Fixing it:**
Now that your remote has the changes you made, you can checkout the `branch_name` and pull your changes from remote. Your `branch_name` should already be tracking that remote branch.

**Why you had to do this:** You somehow detached your head. Without knowing the commands you used, we won't be able to tell you why you had to do this.

An example of how you could have done this:

```
#Don't do this, because force pulling will make you lose your work.
git checkout --detach
git pull --all -f #Don't do this.
```

Comment: *After checking out the branch of a colleague* – it was probably `git checkout origin/something`. Just guessin'.

Comment: I found where I might have gone off road. When I checked-out the branch I was going to work on, I got this message (let's called the branch `b1`: `Branch b1 set up to track remote branch b1 from origin. Switched to a new branch 'b1'`. I checked-out the branch this way: `git checkout b1`. Then when I tried to push I did: `git push --set-upstream origin b1. Branch b1 set up to track remote branch b1 from origin. Everything up to date`.